# Is good idea to split the JSONB field into a separate table in my case?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

In my case I have a table named clients that follows the following information:

```
store_listing:
#######
id SERIAL PK
title VARCHAR(100) not null
features JSONB not null
comments TEXT
vat_num VARCHAR(100) NOT null
```

This table I use to generate:

1. Client listings (for example csv generations for various 3rd party services)
2. Change banners to website for various promos
3. Enable and disable various features that client has access to.

A typical value can be:

```
{
   banner_cats:{
      active: true,
      types: ['persian','aegean']
   },
   promo_petfest_2023:{
     active: true,
     meta: ['dogs','cats','giraqffes']
   },
   1bank_catzoo: {
     active: true
   },
   feature_virtual_pet: {
     active: true
   }
}
```

Each time I need to flag and place meta to a specific Store_listing I need to update the `features` column. Also in my case promos can be generated on the fly according for example a big organization (e.g. WWE) wants to make a promo where will place special banners to my website Therefore I'll have to update the integration column like this:

```
{
   banner_cats:{
      active: true,
      types: ['persian','aegean']
   },
   promo_petfest_2023:{
     active: true,
     meta: ['dogs','cats','giraqffes']
   },
   1bank_catzoo: {
     active: true
   },
   feature_virtual_pet: {
     active: true
   },
   wwe_wild_beast_payperview:{
      active: true
   }
}
```

That seems like a bad decision to me therefore I thought this approach:

```
features_and_promos_settings
####
listing_id FK store_listing
identifier: String (lowercase, does not contain spaces)
active: boolean
meta: jsonb
type: ENUM(PROMO,FEATURE,BANNER) NULL
#####
PK (listing_id, identifier)
```

So in my case the `integrations` column will contain this value (listing_id = 1) :

```
{
   banner_cats:{
      active: true,
      types: ['persian','aegean']
   },
   promo_petfest_2023:{
     active: true,
     meta: ['dogs','cats','giraqffes']
   },
   1bank_catzoo: {
     active: true
   },
   feature_virtual_pet: {
     active: true
   },
   wwe_wild_beast_payperview:{
      active: true
   }
}
```

Will turn into records in `features_and_promos_settings`

| listing_id | identifier | active | meta | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | banner_cats | true | {types: ['persian','aegean']} | BANNER |
| 1 | promo_petfest_2023 | true | {meta: ['dogs','cats','giraqffes']} | PROMO |
| 1 | 1bank_catzoo | TRUE | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | feature_virtual_pet | TRUE | NULL | FEATURE |
| 1 | wwe_wild_beast_payperview | TRUE | NULL | BANNER |

But would this approach will benefit me in cases such as searching and resource usage during select. The RDMS that I'll use is postgresql-11.

I expect that may reports will be generated for KPIS (e.g. to answer questions How many listings did participate in a specific promo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that splitting up the JSON array into a set of rows in a table is certainly a good idea. Your updates will become faster, and your queries won't become slower.